# Rails self-referential has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, self-reference

Using Ruby on Rails, I think I need to create a self-referential has_many association to model words in Chinese.

Background:

Each word is a **composite** of multiple **component** words.

For example, if I have three words, 'ni', 'hao', and 'nihao', I want to be able to do:

`nihao.components = ['ni', 'hao']`
and
`'ni'.composites = ['nihao']`
`'hao'.composites =['nihao']`

I don't believe this should be a hierarchical association (I've seen several gems... ) because a word doesn't have 1 or 2 "parents", it has 0, 1, or hundreds of "composites". Likewise a word has 0, 1, or several "components".

I've tried:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :components, through: :relationships, foreign_key: :component_id
  has_many :composites, through: :relationships, foreign_key: :composite_id
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component, class_name: "Word"
  belongs_to :composite, class_name: "Word"
end
```

This isn't quite correct as I am unable to add components:

```
nihao.components << ni
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'word_id' for Relationship.
        from (irb):5
```

Database schema:

```
create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "component_id"
    t.integer "composite_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "words", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "characters"
    t.string "pinyin"
    t.string "opinyin"
    t.string "tpinyin"
    t.string "english"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Can you add schema of these two models? @Daniel

Comment: Thanks @AakashGupta, I added schema into the original question (couldn't figure out how to add code block to comments!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you were not associating your models properly for this kind of use case.

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :component_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: :composite_id
  has_many :composite_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: :component_id

  has_many :components, through: :component_relationships
  has_many :composites, through: :composite_relationships
end 

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component, class_name: "Word", foreign_key: :component_id
  belongs_to :composite, class_name: "Word", foreign_key: :composite_id
end
```

I have not tried this, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: Nailed it.  Thx.